# Do the interpretations given in the Gemara (Berachos 57) for seeing various things in a dream also apply if someone dreams that he is dreaming them?

Tags: dream

The Gemara in Berachos (57a) brings many different dreams and explains their interpretations.

Do these interpretations apply also if someone dreams that he is asleep and is dreaming those dreams or only if the dreams present themselves as if they were were a real life situation?

Comment: And what if he dreams that he dreamed that he dreamed them...?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות If we could find a source to prove that a dream of a dream has the same interpretation as a "live" dream than I would assume that so would dreams of dreams of dreams etc.

Comment: http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01089.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2

Comment: @רבותמחשבות What should I find there?